# HTML Graph With MySQL using Javascript PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, canvas

Hi the below PHP is Fetching the result as below but the problem is i need to integrate with the JavaScript i.e. data Points to show the same result in a Graphical representation

The PHP Out put is as below:

```
{ y: 4,label: James },
{ y: 5,label: Mathews },
{ y: 6,label: Arnold },
{ y: 7,label: William },
```

DB Code:

```
$mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','Reg');




            $selname = $_POST['storedValue'];
        $query ="SELECT * FROM master WHERE  StudentRegID='$selname' ";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
$num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {



      echo "{ y: ".$row[3].",label: ".$row[6]." },<br/>";

    }

mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

JavaScript Code:
The Below code for Data point is manually But The Result should b Printed of above

```
data:[
    {        
        type: "stackedBar100",
        showInLegend: true, 
        name: "Presrnt",
        dataPoints: [

            {y: 0, label: "Modern Chair" },
            {y: 120, label: "VOIP Phone" },
            {y: 250, label: "Microwave" },
            {y: 120, label: "Water Filter" },
            {y: 374, label: "Expresso Machine" },
            {y: 374, label: "Expresso Machine" },
            {y: 350, label: "Lobby Chair" },
        ]
    },
    {        
        type: "stackedBar100",
        showInLegend: true, 
        name: "Absent",
        dataPoints: [

        {y: 1, label: "Modern Chair" },
        {y: 220, label: "VOIP Phone" },
        {y: 350, label: "Microwave" },
        {y: 220, label: "Water Filter" },
        {y: 474, label: "Expresso Machine" },
        {y: 474, label: "Expresso Machine" },
        {y: 450, label: "Lobby Chair" },
    ]
}
]
```

As the data is Fetched using ajax i have a response in a dive and am using to point it to the data point

```
 var temp =  document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked on something very similar lately and I used this method:

Javascript:

```
var dps = [];
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
        title: {
            text: "Stats"
        },
        animationEnabled: true,
        height: 650,
        width: $(".slide-content").width(),
        theme: "theme2",
        data: [

            {
                type: "column",
                dataPoints: dps
            }
        ]
    });
```

Then to update the chart via a ajax request:

```
function updatechart()
{
    dps.length = 0;

    $.getJSON("http://example.com", function (result) {

        $.each(result, function() {
            dps.push(this);
        });

        chart.render();
    });

}
```

PHP:

```
$output = [];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT date,value FROM `stats`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    $output[] = array("label" => "Date: ".$row[0], "y" => $row[1]);

}

$result = json_encode($output);
die($result);
```

Comment: the link in the ajax request, does it return any data?